# Java Regex replace : and / except the domain name in the url to white space

Tags: java, regex, url

I have a long string, including lots of `:` and `/`. It also includes urls.

I want to replace all `:` and `/` but the domain name (e.g., `http://example.com`) of the url's to white space.

So `link:http://example.com/test/page.html` will become `link http://example.com test page.html`.

I tried `replaceAll("[://]", " ")` but it also replaces `:` and `/` in `http://example.com` to white space.

Comment: Replace or remove?

Comment: Replace to white space, as in the example.

Comment: How should your code react for `url:http://example.com//foo/bar`?

Comment: Why don't you use `replaceFirst()`?

Comment: It should give `url http://example.com  foo bar`

Comment: Are there two spaces between `.com` and `foo` or one?

Comment: I wrote two spaces, but also one space is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now it looks like you may want to use something like:

```
url = url.replaceAll("(https?://[^/:]+)?[/:]", "$1 ")
```

`$1` represents match from group 1 `(https?://[^/:]+)` which thanks to `?` is optional.

So it will try to find any `/` or `:` and replace it with space. If before any of these characters there is `http://address` part it will be replaced by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to keep some pattern in one context and replace with something else in the other, you can use the regex to match and *capture* URLs (and anything you want to "protect") and just match what you need to remove. Then, use `Matcher#appendReplacement()` to check if the capture took place, and use the appropriate replacement accordingly.

The regex can be similar to `(\\bhttps?://\\S*)|[:/]` where `(\\bhttps?://)` matches and *captures into Group 1* a `http://` or `https://`, and `[:/]` matches either `:` or `/` (to be replaced with a space). If you need to "shrink" the `/`s and `:`s, use `[:/]+`.

Here is a sample code:

```
String fileText = "http://example.com//foo/bar http://example.com//foo/bar  1: 2/";
String pattern = "(\\bhttps?://)|[:/]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(fileText);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null)
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1));
    else
        m.appendReplacement(sb, " ");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
// => http://example.com  foo bar http://example.com  foo bar  1  2
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/lzACQw).

Comment: I don't see how this gives the desired result? When I run it, I get "http://example.com//foo/bar  1  2 "

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis you are right. It does not replace `//fo/bar` to `fo bar`.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not replace //fo/bar to fo bar"? Should it? See http://ideone.com/lzACQw

Comment: I see, before the edit, my answer was 100% correct, now, it is also correct, but Pshemo's approach is more concise.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your answer is now 100% correct, but before the edit, the pattern was `"(\\bhttps?://\\S*)|[:/]"` that didn't replace `//fo/bar` to `foo bar`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, because your requirements were not 100% clear, and it is very strange someone would want to break a URL.